# How to include a time partition with insert query in Java API

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to figure out how to use the Java API to insert data into a new time partition with an existing table.  I am able to do this via the CLI with something like:

> bq query --use_legacy_sql=false --allow_large_results --replace --destination_table 'analytics.base_client_qos$20170104' 'SELECT *, CAST(SUBSTR(event_date_pst, 0, 10) AS DATE) as dt from analytics.client_qos_temp'

I tried creating this via the Java API using something like:

```
String projectId =  "analytics-145623";
String datasetId = "analytics";
String destTableId = "'analytics.base_client_qos$20170104'";
String queryString = "'SELECT *, CAST(SUBSTR(event_date_pst, 0, 10) AS DATE) as dt from analytics.client_qos_temp'";

// first create the new time partition
TableReference tableRef = new TableReference()
    .setProjectId(projectId)
    .setDatasetId(datasetId)
    .setTableId(destTableId);
Table table = new Table();
TimePartitioning timePartitioning = new TimePartitioning();
timePartitioning.setType("DAY");
table.setTimePartitioning(timePartitioning);
table.setTableReference(tableRef);
Bigquery.Tables.Insert request = client.tables().insert(projectId, datasetId, table);
Table response = request.execute();

// next run query to insert the data
JobConfigurationQuery queryConfig = new JobConfigurationQuery()
    .setQuery(querySql)
    .setDestinationTable(tableRef)
    .setAllowLargeResults(true)
    .setUseLegacySql(false)
    .setPriority("BATCH")
    .setWriteDisposition("WRITE_TRUNCATE");
Job job = new Job().setConfiguration(new JobConfiguration().setQuery(queryConfig));
client.jobs().insert(projectId, job).execute();
```

but this errors out with:

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid table ID \"'analytics.base_client_qos$20170104'\".",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid table ID \"'analytics.base_client_qos$20170104'\"."
}
```

I dug into the API docs and the only place that you can add the time partition info is on the Table with the TimePartitioning, but it is clearly not working and hung up on the name of the partition.

What am I missing.  I tried to find an example of doing this, but no luck.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating new table, you should not use partition suffix `$20170104`, just use `analytics.base_client_qos` in the `client.tables().insert` call.
But when you `.setDestinationTable` for the query, use partition name `analytics.base_client_qos$20170104`

Answer (score 0):

After looking more closely, I decided against the tables(), because that is for the streaming of records into the the table, this is just not going to work out for the volumes we have.  I asked different questions and decided to skip the temp table, do the pre-processing in Hive and use a load instead of the insert query, and this did work out better for me.  For the next guy who comes along, it went something like this:

```
String cloudStoragePath = "gs://analytics-145623.appspot.com/user/hive/warehouse/di.db/base_client_qos_daily/year=2017/month=1/day=4/*.avro";
String projectId =  "analytics-145623";
String datasetId = "analytics";
String destTableId = "base_client_qos$20170104";

TableReference tableRef = new TableReference()
    .setProjectId(projectId)
    .setDatasetId(datasetId)
    .setTableId(destTableId);

JobConfigurationLoad loadTable = new JobConfigurationLoad()
    .setDestinationTable(tableRef)
    .setSourceFormat("AVRO")
    .setSourceUris(Collections.singletonList(cloudStoragePath))
    .setWriteDisposition("WRITE_TRUNCATE");
Job loadJob =  client.jobs().insert(table.getProjectId(), 
                        new Job().setConfiguration(new JobConfiguration().setLoad(loadTable))
                    ).execute();
Bigquery.Jobs.Get tempTableGet = client.jobs()
    .get(tempTableJob.getJobReference().getProjectId(), 
    tempTableJob.getJobReference().getJobId());

Job jobResult = BigQueryUtils.pollJob(tempTableGet, interval);
if (jobResult == null || jobResult.getStatus().getErrorResult() != null) {
    System.out.println("Error when overwritting temp table: " + 
            jobResult.getStatus().getErrorResult().getReason());
}
```

HTH